# JAVA Visual Representation

Tags: java, swing, image-processing, javafx

I have been searching for quite a bit on a way to make static visual representations of Java, but im not certain that what i found to be the most correct way to accomplish what im looking for.

I looking for a way to simply produce an image to represent the state of a board in Java. For example, lets say i have an implementation of Checkers in Java, what im looking for is a way to, after each individual move, represent the game board.

I have looked into JavaFX and Swing, but judging from what i found out they are more suited for actual dynamic GUI's, not image processing( tho i can be wrong).

What options are there really? Or should i use any external apps/software for this?

Comment: Perhaps you should have a look at [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) and [Getting Started with Graphics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/basic2d/index.html)

Comment: `what im looking for is a way to, after each individual move, represent the game board.` - if you mean you just want to create an image, then you can use the [Screen Image](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/13/screen-image/) class. It allows you to create an image of any Swing component.

Comment: "what im looking for is a way to, after each individual move, represent the game board" -> how is that not an "actual dynamic GUI"?  Can you better explain what you are trying to do?  What are "static visual representations of Java"?

Comment: Camickr, given the option to not use swing I would prefer , since it would be a pain constantly creating panes and such every time an action is performed

Comment: Jewelsea, because it is simply not a gui and it is not dynamic , it's doesn't change nor take any input , what k am looking for is simply to produce an image after every action, not looking for an "updatable" gui of some sort

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like this (a JavaFX solution) which will render images of a checkerboard to png files.  Not sure if that is what you are looking for as your question was a bit unclear to me, but perhaps it is helpful for you.

[image: snapshot-0]

---

[image: snapshot-1]

---

[image: snapshot-2]

```
import javafx.application.*;
import javafx.embed.swing.SwingFXUtils;
import javafx.scene.*;
import javafx.scene.image.WritableImage;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Checkout extends Application {

    private static final double SQUARE_SIZE = 20;
    private static final double PIECE_RADIUS = SQUARE_SIZE / 2.5;

    private static final Color WHITE = Color.BEIGE;
    private static final Color BLACK = Color.ROSYBROWN;

    // setupindex, player, position (1-32 index into top to bottom black squares on the board).
    private static final int[][][] setups =
            {
                    {
                            {31, 27, 19},
                            {17, 12, 5}
                    },
                    {
                            {30, 26, 18},
                            {19, 11, 10},
                    },
                    {
                            {31, 24, 19},
                            {18, 11, 10}
                    }
            };
    private static final String SNAPSHOT_FILE_PREFIX = "snapshot-";
    private static final String SNAPSHOT_FILE_SUFFIX = ".png";

    private WritableImage snapshotFxImage =
            new WritableImage((int) (SQUARE_SIZE * 8), (int) (SQUARE_SIZE * 8));
    private BufferedImage snapshotBufferedImage =
            new BufferedImage((int) (SQUARE_SIZE * 8), (int) (SQUARE_SIZE * 8), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);

    private static final String USER_HOME =
            System.getProperties().getProperty("user.home");


    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {
        Group layout = new Group();
        renderBoard(layout);
        Scene scene = new Scene(layout);

        int i = 0;
        for (int[][] setup : setups) {
            List<Node> pieces = renderSetup(setup);
            layout.getChildren().addAll(pieces);
            snapshot(scene, i);
            layout.getChildren().removeAll(pieces);

            i++;
        }

        Platform.setImplicitExit(false);
        Platform.exit();
    }

    private void renderBoard(Group layout) {
        for (int r = 0; r < 8; r++) {
            for (int c = 0; c < 8; c++) {
                Rectangle square = new Rectangle(
                        c * SQUARE_SIZE,
                        r * SQUARE_SIZE,
                        SQUARE_SIZE,
                        SQUARE_SIZE
                );

                Color fill =
                        (((c + r) % 2) == 0)
                                ? Color.WHITE
                                : Color.BLACK;
                square.setFill(fill);

                layout.getChildren().add(square);
            }
        }
    }

    private List<Node> renderSetup(int[][] setup) {
        List<Node> pieces = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int player = 0; player < 2; player++) {
            for (int pieceIndex = 0; pieceIndex < setup[player].length; pieceIndex++) {
                Color fill =
                        player == 0
                                ? WHITE
                                : BLACK;
                Circle piece = new Circle(PIECE_RADIUS, fill);

                pieces.add(piece);
                movePieceTo(piece, setup[player][pieceIndex]);
            }
        }

        return pieces;
    }

    private void movePieceTo(Circle circle, int p) {
        int r = (p - 1) / 4;
        int c = ((p - 1) % 4) * 2 + (((r % 2) == 0) ? 1 : 0);

        circle.setCenterX(c * SQUARE_SIZE + SQUARE_SIZE / 2);
        circle.setCenterY(r * SQUARE_SIZE + SQUARE_SIZE / 2);
    }

    private void snapshot(Scene scene, int snapshotIdx) throws IOException {
        Path path = Paths.get(
                USER_HOME,
                SNAPSHOT_FILE_PREFIX + snapshotIdx + SNAPSHOT_FILE_SUFFIX
        );
        scene.snapshot(snapshotFxImage);
        SwingFXUtils.fromFXImage(snapshotFxImage, snapshotBufferedImage);
        ImageIO.write(snapshotBufferedImage, "png", path.toFile());

        System.out.println("Saved: " + path.toString());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `Graphics` class to draw to an in memory image. Then you can save that to a file or display it some way. Heres an example of how you might get started doing that:

```
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class SO45990731 {

    public static void main(String [] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(500, 500, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);

        Graphics g = image.getGraphics();

        // TODO draw your checker board
        g.drawOval(100, 100, 300, 300);

        // cleanup and write
        g.dispose();
        ImageIO.write(image, "png", new File("board.png"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Not the prettiest solution but solves the problem in a simple way , thank you very much

Comment: @eXistanCe This way is a pretty standard way of drawing images in Java. You could also consider reading in an image of your board, then drawing the peices (or placing them from other images using `g.drawImage()`) onto a result. This would make it alot easier to create a pretty output without doing it all in java.

Comment: @eXistanCe almost forgot, the `Graphics` object can be cast to the `Graphics2D` class, giving your more functionality for drawing.

Comment: You mean loading a custom image of the board and then using that class to draw the pieces ?

Comment: @eXistanCe You could keep an image of a chessboard, a red piece, a black piece and a king version of both in your project. Just load those images in and draw them onto your new image, this way you can make them look pretty. Also it would be quite easy.